# Does Gromov's Waist Inequality imply Borsuk-Ulam?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

I'm curious if anyone can see a route to get the Borsuk-Ulam theorem from Gromov's waist inequality. For the sake of notation, here's the inequality:

Let $S^n$ denote the round unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. It carries the spherical        measure which we denote $vol(\cdot)$ and a Riemannian metric which induces a distance function $d(\cdot,\cdot)$. We write $S^{n-k}$ for the  equatorial $(n-k)$-sphere inside $S^n$:
        $$ S^{n-k} = \{ (x_1, \dots, x_{n+1}) \in S^n : x_i = 0, i>n-k+1\} $$
 For a continuous map $f : S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ we write $S_z = \{s \in S^n : f(s) = z\}$ for the level sets of $f$. Write $U_\epsilon(S) =  \{\sigma \in S^n : d(\sigma, S) < \epsilon\}$ for an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of a subset $S$.

> **Theorem (Gromov):** If $f : S^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ is continuous then there is a point $z \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that: $$ vol(U_\epsilon(S_z)) \geq vol(U_\epsilon(S^{n-k})) $$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

This inequality is quite strong. It implies the spherical isoperimetric inequality. It also implies topological invariance of domain. For more background, see Guth's survey [The Waist Inequality in Gromov's Work](http://math.mit.edu/~lguth/Exposition/waist.pdf).

Getting back to my question: If $n=k$ and the level set given by the inequality contains two points then taking $\epsilon = \pi/2$ gives the Borsuk-Ulam theorem. Can one arrange for this to always happen and hence derive Borsuk-Ulam?

Comment: I think Gromov mentions this case in his paper.

Comment: @alvarezpaiva: Now that you mention it, I remember reading Gromovs paper and noticing that he is careful enough to write $\operatorname{card}f^{-1}(z)\leq 2$. I edited my answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yashar Mermarian writes [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3972) that the answer is yes. And the argument he gives is pretty much the same as the one you already started.

Taking $n=k$ and $\epsilon=\pi/2$ Gromov's waist inequality gives a point $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$$vol(U_{\pi/2}(S_Z))\geq vol(U_{\pi/2}(S^0))=vol(U_{\pi/2}(\{(1,0,\dots,0),(-1,0,\dots,0)\})=vol(S^n).$$
It follows that $U_{\pi/2}(S_Z)$ has to have the same volume as the sphere. This can only be the case when $S_Z$ contains at least $2$ elements, since the volume of $U_\epsilon(S_Z)$ would be to small otherwise. If it contains $2$ elements and not more, these $2$ elements would have to be antipodal, otherwise the volume of $U_\epsilon(S_Z)$ would be to small again. 
Although Memarian writes there "is no choice" for $S_Z$ but to "pass through antipodal points", I don't really see how one can rule out that $S_Z$ might consist of more than two points.

This gives the following (weaker) version of a Bursuk Ulam type result:

> If $f:\; S^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, then $f$ maps two antipodal points in $S^n$ to the same point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $f$ maps (at least) three points to the same point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

[image: two semispheres]  $U_{\pi/2}$ for two points which are not antipodal.

In the [original paper](http://www.ihes.fr/~gromov/PDF/waists.pdf) Gromov is more careful. He writes:

> If $k=n$, and $\operatorname{card}(f^{-1}(z))\leq 2$, $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$, then [the waist of the sphere theorem] applied to $\pi/2$ amounts to the Borsuk–Ulam theorem: some level $f^{-1}(z)$ of $f\;:S^n\to \mathbb{R}^k$ equals a pair of opposite points.

Of course $f^{-1}(z)$ is just a different notation of $S_Z$. So the important detail is: "and $\operatorname{card}(f^{-1}(z))\leq 2$".

In general $\operatorname{card}(f^{-1}(z))\leq 2$ is not true for arbitrary maps. And even if you perturbe $f$ a little bit this condition won't be fullfilled. Of course any two maps from $S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ are homotopic, so in particular $f$ will be homotopic to a map with $\operatorname{card}(f^{-1}(z))\leq 2$ for all $z$, but this doesn't really give you anything.

To summarize the answer is: Gromov's Waist Inequality almost implies Borsuk-Ulam.

Comment: In Mermarian's write up, the only statement I take issue with is this: "But the right hand side of the inequality is equal the total volume of the sphere, so there is no choice for $f^{-1}(z)$ but to pass through two diametrically opposite points." There are certainly $S \subset S^n$ such that $vol(U_\epsilon(S)) \geq vol(U_\epsilon(S^0))$ for all $\epsilon$ but $S \cap (-S) = \emptyset$.

I guess the problem is: How generic are function $f : S^n \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^n$ such that $|f^{-1}(z)| \leq 2$ for all $z \in \mathbf{R}^n$?

Comment: I also take issue with this. I guess Mermarian implicitly presume $|f^{-1}(z)|\leq2$. I will add a line about the fact that this is a serious restriction.