# Is there a connection between |roots| $\rightarrow$ 1 and Gromov's waist theorem?

Tags: pr.probability, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Recent questions showed that roots of a random polynomial tend to lie on the
unit circle ("[Why do roots of polynomials tend to have absolute value close to 1?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182412/6094)"; "[Distribution of roots of complex polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/q/139804/6094)").

I wonder if this fact can be somehow seen as a consequence of (or at least related to)
[Gromov's waist theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/148825/6094)?
Can Andrej Bauer's [image](https://mathoverflow.net/q/182412/6094) be viewed as a
projection to the plane of a sphere whose waist is dense in roots?